# Howto list files on a smartcard with pyscard

Tags: python, smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader, pyscard

I have to read out a file from a smartcard. The card is written by a digital tachograph that monitors vehicle movements. I could connect to the smartcard reader with psycard (http://pyscard.sourceforge.net/user-guide.html) but then I don't know how to list files on the card and how to download them. I was digging the ISO standards and it looks like I have to use ISO/IEC 7816 standard, and dedicated files (http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_5_basic_organizations.aspx) but I don't know how to do it from pyscard?

There are already programs out there (for example: http://en.tachoterminal.net/products/tachoterminal-reader/) that do exactly the same thing, but they are stand alone programs. I need to integrate this functionality into another software.

I don't know which protocol to use. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: A smart card is no USB memory stick. A command to find out, which files are present, may exist or not (Michaels link should provide you with all knowledge necessary not to need the command) and *downloading* is a concept rather untypical in smartcard environment. Maybe you are allowed to read *some* files then do so step by step, but don't be surprised, if this is only a small subset.

Comment: I did not doubt the existence of files but wanted to point out, that additional knowledge (e.g. a secret key or authentication certificate) might be necessary in addition to the mere technical knowledge, how files are read out in principle. That programs exist, which are able to read something (as you mention) does not mean, everybody can read the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer I assume you are refering to a tachograph driver card according to the ECC regulation No 3821/85. In that case, you are right that the smartcard communicates using ISO/IEC 7816-4 APDUs and that it exposes a file structure based on ISO/IEC 7816-4.

Once you opened a connection to the card using pyscard, you can call the `transmit()` method on that connection object to transsceive APDUs (also see [Ludovic Rousseau's blog](http://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.co.at/2010/04/pcsc-sample-in-python.html):

```
connection = reader.createConnection()
connection.connect()
data, sw1, sw2 = connection.transmit(cmd)
```

The communication flow with the tachograph driver card would be something like the following:

1. SELECT tachograph application

   ```
   00 A4 04 0C 06 FF544143484F
   ```

   For this command, `cmd` would be:

   ```
   cmd = [ 0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x0C, 0x06, 0xFF, 0x54, 0x41, 0x43, 0x48, 0x4F ]
   ```
2. SELECT elementary file by file identifier (`xxxx`)

   ```
   00 A4 02 0C 02 xxxx
   ```
3. READ BINARY to get file data (`zz` bytes from offset `xxyy`)

   ```
   00 B0 xx yy zz
   ```

You can find a complete specification of the driver card's protocol and data structures as part of the regulation document ([here](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CONSLEG:1985R3821:20111001:EN:PDF)).

Comment: Select elementary file wit file id= EF_ICC = [0x00,0x02 ] gave me sw1=0x6A, sw2=0x86 meaning:"File identifier not found". I suspect that the card is damaged so I'm going to try this with another card tomorrow.

Comment: Note that EF_ICC is below the master file (and not below the tachograph application DF). Hence, you would need to select the master file first (or at least *not* perform selection of the tachograph application DF).

Comment: In step (2) of my answer you could try to select EF_Application_Identification (`[ 0x05, 0x01]`).

Comment: My fault. It was a typo. I have managed to open and read files. Do you have some documentation that shows how to save these into a ddd file? By any chance.